# How to do TLS 1.3 PSK using openssl?

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'm working on a client/server software and trying to figure out how to setup a TLS 1.3 PSK connection using openssl. Apparently, there are different callbacks as compared to TLS 1.2 (and lower) but openssl documentation is dreadful and I can't really understand the full flow.

Can someone provide sample code on how to return info in these callbacks?

```
int SSL_psk_use_session_cb_func(SSL *ssl, const EVP_MD *md,const unsigned char **id,size_t *idlen,SSL_SESSION **sess);   

int (*SSL_psk_find_session_cb_func)(SSL *ssl,const unsigned char *identity,size_t identity_len,SSL_SESSION **sess);
```

1. My understanding was that in TLS1.3 the Identity Hint is NULL, then why do these TLS1.3 specific callbacks have identity fields in them?
2. Read somewhere that TLS 1.3 has a different set of ciphersuites, what are the names of ones for PSK AES256 and PSK CHACHA20
3. In my case, the server will only accept one connection i.e. P2P datalink. Do I still have to make one side act as a server i.e. use find_session_cb instead of use_session_cb?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can someone provide sample code on how to return info in these callbacks?

You can take a look at how s_client does it here:

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/6af1b11848f000c900877f1289a42948d415f21c/apps/s_client.c#L183-L243

And here is how s_server does it:

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/6af1b11848f000c900877f1289a42948d415f21c/apps/s_server.c#L185-L232

> My understanding was that in TLS1.3 the Identity Hint is NULL, then why do these TLS1.3 specific callbacks have identity fields in them?

Identity Hint and Identity are two different things. In TLSv1.2 a server could provide a hint to the client to allow the client to select the correct identity for that server. In TLSv1.3 PSKs work completely differently. The client sends the identity to the server in the very first message so there is no opportunity for a hint to be received. In practice hints aren't usually that useful anyway.

In the context of PSK you can think of an identity as a bit like a username (that's actually a bit of an over-simplification - but enough for our purposes here)

> Read somewhere that TLS 1.3 has a different set of ciphersuites, what are the names of ones for PSK AES256 and PSK CHACHA20

In TLSv1.2 you needed to use special PSK ciphersuites. In TLSv1.3 that is no longer the case. Ciphersuites work quite differently and there is no concept of having special PSK ciphersuites. You just use the normal ciphersuites. The main thing to be wary of is that in TLSv1.3 a PSK is always associated with a hash (e.g. SHA256). Whatever ciphersuite you use must be compatible with that hash, e.g. for SHA256 you might use TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 or TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256.

> In my case, the server will only accept one connection i.e. P2P datalink. Do I still have to make one side act as a server i.e. use find_session_cb instead of use_session_cb?

In TLS the client is defined as the peer that initiates the communication and the server is the peer that receives incoming connections. Therefore there is *always* a client and a server role. So, yes, one side must use `find_session_cb` and the other side must use `use_session_cb`.

Comment: Can you explain "a PSK is always associated with a hash" a bit more? I read about it somewhere else, but they didn't provide any details either, so just want to wrap my head around this. Mainly I'm confused by How PSK is associated with a Hash and implications of it. AFAIK, PSK is a just random number of bytes that act as pre-shared secret so where does hash come into play?

Comment: The PSK itself is not used directly as the key to encrypt messages. A KDF (Key Derivation Function) is used to derive a key that is shared between the client and the server. One of the inputs to that KDF is the PSK value. Another input is an (EC)DHE shared secret, i.e. a value derived via a cryptographic algorithm using data contained in the handshake. In this way the key that is actually used in any given connection is different every time - even if you use the same PSK. In order for the KDF to work it uses a hash algorithm (such as SHA256).

Comment: The TLSv1.3 spec says that every PSK must have an associated hash algorithm, and it is that which is used by the KDF.

Comment: Went through the sample code, Few questions:

1. What is going on [here?](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/6af1b11848f000c900877f1289a42948d415f21c/apps/s_client.c#L226). OpenSSL doc says to specify Hash alogirthm but the code is checking for Null pointer and whether Cipher's EVP_MD pointer is same as provided pointer. Why is that? Also, I didn't get the whole if/else reasoning here.

2. The code is also specifying One cipher, what if I wanted to have option of two on the server side, so that client using one of them can connect?

Comment: See doc here: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_psk_use_session_callback.html In particular the 3rd paragraph on that page. Normally the use_session_cb is called once in the handshake, but sometimes it can be called twice. The first time the md passed as a parmater to the cb is always NULL. In such a case we can just ignore it. If it gets called a second time then an md will be specified and it *must* be compatible with the md associated with the PSK. So this if is first checking whether md is non NULL and if so it checks that the md is compatible with the PSK.

Comment: In OpenSSL PSKs are represented as SSL_SESSION objects. This is because TLSv1.3 uses the same mechanism for PSKs that it does for resuming sessions, i.e. if you're just doing normal TLS (no PSKs) then after you've connected the first time you establish a session with the server. When you create a new connection you "resume" using the details from the original session. PSKs and sessions are indistinguishable in TLSv1.3. As noted in the doc I linked to when setting up an SSL_SESSION object to use as a PSK you need to set 3 fieds: the master key, a ciphersuite and the protocol version.

Comment: From the docs: "Only the handshake digest associated with the ciphersuite is relevant for the PSK (the server may go on to negotiate any ciphersuite which is compatible with the digest)". So you can pick any ciphersuite you like as long as the digest (aka hash) is compatible with the ciphersuite that is eventually negotiated.

Comment: I got it working, however, noticed something weird. TLS 1.3 PSK (cipher: tls13_aes256_gcm_sha384_id) should have a 1 RT handshake but I'm seeing 2 round trips?
C -> S = 295 bytes, 
S -> C = 241, 
C -> S = 80  - Client do_handshake() returns 1, err() returns 0, but bio_ctrl_pending() returns 80 bytes - which I HAVE to send to Server for do_handshake to return success, 

S -> C = 255  -   Even though Server handshake is complete and err() returns 0, it also reports 255 pending write bytes via bio_ctrl_pending().

Comment: Probably that is the topic of a separate question for us to get to the bottom of!

Comment: My code had been working fine, using the sample callback code you mentioned in your original answer. Today I tried to use different ciphers i.e. tls13_aes128gcmsha256_id and chacha20_poly1305_sha256. Both are causing handshake to fail with server side reporting error "20504:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:ssl\\record\\rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 40"
I suspect its due to SHA256 md?

Comment: Found the problem. Turns out I have to specifically set ciphersuites using 'SSL_set_ciphersuites' because openssl was defaulting to "tls13_aes256_gcm_sha384" on the server side resulting in error.

Comment: Can you look into my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59519968/random-failure-of-ssl-read This one has been baffling me for days and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

I hope you meant externally established PSK (out-of-band PSK key and ID) with TLSv1.3. For that you can directly use old callbacks `psk_client_callback` and `psk_server_callback`. With these callback, by default `AES_128_GCM_WITH_SHA256` ciphersuite gets used.

TLSv1.3 PSK [client](https://github.com/TalkWithTLS/TalkWithTLS/blob/master/src/sample/openssl_tls13_psk_out_of_band_client.c), [server](https://github.com/TalkWithTLS/TalkWithTLS/blob/master/src/sample/openssl_tls13_psk_out_of_band_server.c) example in this [repo](https://github.com/TalkWithTLS/TalkWithTLS)

Here the `ClientHello` msg sends `pre_shared_key` extension with the PSK_ID. And the `ServerHello` responds with `pre_shared_key` extension with chosen PSK_ID index as 0.

[image]

[image]

If you need to use different ciphersuites then you need to use `psk_use_session_cb` and `psk_find_session_cb`.